# Component returned failure code: 0x80004005

Tags: exception, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

This error triggers only sometimes when I do an `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
uncaught exception: 
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
[nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]" nsresult: "0x80004005 
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: 
file://.../Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/.../extensions/.../components/greasemonkey.js 
:: anonymous :: line 1332" data: no
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Look in the windows event log and see what other information is recorded

Comment: no other information is recorded

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm getting the same 0x80004005 error calling window.location.host - it's literally the first call in the script. googling, 0x80004005 seems to be the Swiss Army knife of mozilla errors - it can turn up literally anywhere and break anything for any reason.

Comment: Are you using AdBlock?
Try disabling it.