# redactor Js | wysiwyg jquery | error on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, wysiwyg

I use the wysiwyg Redactor js (wysiwyg jquery) and I have a problem with firefox.
http://redactorjs.com/
when I run the plugin like this

```
$ ('# news_content'). redactor ({focus: true});
```

firebug return me this error :

```
Returned Component failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]
this.doc.execCommand ("useCSS", false, true);
```

It works fine on Chrome, IE, Opera but not on firefox
Any ideas of my problem ?
Thanx a lot for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Make sure you have wrapped that statement in a ready handler like this:</strike>

```
$(function(){
    $ ('# news_content'). redactor ({focus: true});
});
```

This is caused by Ajax security policies.

[Component returned failure code: 0x80004005](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5075710/221061)

and

[Component returned failure code: 0x80004005](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2743147/221061)

are both questions that describe the problem.

Comment: the code is in a script tag in the bottom of the ajax page
**it works fine on Chrome,IE,Opera**

Comment: Ok, still try my snippet though.

Comment: Are you using Ajax anywhere on the page?

Comment: yes, this page is called by ajax
the script is at the end in a script tag

Comment: That means that this is actually caused by Ajax security policies. See these links: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5075710/221061 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2743147/221061. If you post your Ajax code, I might be able to diagnose it better.

Comment: `$.post(  
                    'admin/option',  
                    {  
                        module : module,  
                        fichier : fichier
                    },
                    function(retour){
obj.remplir_contenu(retour);
}`
....
`remplir_contenu : function(content){
        var obj = this;
        $('#content_div').empty().append(content).slideDown(500,function(){
            $(this).animate({
                opacity:1
            },500)
        });
    }`

Comment: I meant the `post`, `get`, `ajax`, or `load` call. Can you post that?